# How do i fill a column on a dataframe with a function thats needs another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, function

I have a dataframe with an A column with three types of texts, and a B Column with dates.

df:

```
A             B
CPI_x6     01/01/2015
CPI        01/01/2015  
CPI_x9     01/03/2015
CPI        01/05/2015
```

And also i have another dataframe VCPI with values:

VCPI :

```
date          CPI_x6   CPI   CPI_x9
01/01/2015    150      200    300
01/02/2015    153      201    200
01/03/2015    152      180    500
01/04/2015    154      170    100
01/05/2015    155      150    600
01/06/2015    156      160    700
01/07/2015    150      170    600
01/08/2015    151      190    500
01/09/2015    149      200    600
01/10/2015    159      210    800
01/11/2015    158      180    900
01/12/2015    155      190    100
```

I would like to create a "C" column in the "df" dataframe with a function like this:

- if A = CPI_x6, calculate an average of 6 months later using VCPI values, starting with the date in column B.
- if A = CPI_x9, calculate an average of 9 months later using VCPI values, starting with the date in column B.
- if A = CPI, take the value of the dataframe VCPI on date assign in column B.

I dont know how can i solve this

Comment: See [windowing functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html) for grouping rows using a sliding range. You'll do this after you `merge()` the dataframes. Then use `df.A` as the column name to reference in `VCPI`

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple.

1. Make `df` for both and save them.
2. Convert column B from 1st and column date from 2nd and convert it into `datetime` format.

Merge both df 1st and that VCPI as:

```
  both_merged_df = pd.merge(df1, vcpi, left_on='B', right_on='date', 
   how='left')
```

Write a function you want according to your condition for example considering 1st situation:

```
 if row['A'] == 'CPI_x6':
    return both_merged_df.loc[(both_merged_df['date'] >= row['B']) & (both_merged_df['date'] <= row['B'] + pd.DateOffset(months=6)), 'CPI_x6'].mean()
```

Then, apply the function to create a new column.

Also, I tried this for me and this is the output might be that will be helpful for you.

[image: output]

Comment: Have you tested this code? I don't think this will work…

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute the [`rolling.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) or each column, then perform an [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
import re

# ensure datetime
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'], dayfirst=False)
VCPI['date'] = pd.to_datetime(VCPI['date'], dayfirst=False)

idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['A'])

df['C'] = (VCPI
  .set_index('date')
  .apply(lambda s: s[::-1].rolling((m.group(0) if (m:=re.search(r'\d+$', s.name)) else '1')+'D',
                                   min_periods=1).mean())
  .loc[df['B'], cols]
  .to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
)
```

Or [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
tmp = (VCPI
  .set_index('date')
  .apply(lambda s: s[::-1].rolling((m.group(0) if (m:=re.search(r'\d+$', s.name)) else '1')+'D',
                                   min_periods=1).mean())
  .reset_index().rename(columns={'date': 'B'}).melt('B', var_name='A', value_name='C')
)

out = df.merge(tmp, on=['A', 'B'], how='left')
```

*NB. this creates a new DataFrame.*

Output:

```
        A          B           C
0  CPI_x6 2015-01-01  153.333333
1     CPI 2015-01-01  200.000000
2  CPI_x9 2015-01-03  588.888889
3     CPI 2015-01-05  150.000000
```

Comment: I realize I used days instead of months and inverted the date format, but the logic remains the same